# What laptop screwdriver should I use?

Tags: compaq-laptop

I have a Compaq presario cq50, and I'd like to upgrade its RAM.

The problem is, I don't have the screw to open it. I didn't find what I need either when I searched the web.

So my question is as it says in the title:  What laptop screwdriver should I use?

On a side note:  An odd and stupid question came to me — are all laptop screws the same? That is, can they all be opened by one particular kind of screwdriver?

Here are the types of screws my laptop has:

[image]

Comment: I think generally speaking you are best suited to answer this question.  Simply look at the screw(s) you need to access and find one.  I am assuming it is probably a star shaped head?  If the screw head is too small but philips head you will probably want to look into a jewelry set of screw drivers,

Comment: I know too little about screws — I don't know what-is-what and which-is-which. If I go to the store, I presume that I'll only be confusing people there with my nebulous descriptions.

Comment: sorry to say, having problems identifying the screwdriver, YOU SHOULDN'T START DISASSEMBLING YOUR DEVICE. You'll quickly face much more complicated (& risky) situations.

Comment: @MátéJuhász absolutely untrue FUD.. An intelligent conscientious person would look for the right screwdriver and may even be pedantic about it being the right one

Comment: I don't recall the sizes to look for.. But i'd be wary of getting any watch screwdrivers as you want to be able to put enough force downwards so the screwdrver doesn't slip out.. otherwise if that happens a bunch of times, you will damage the screwhead more and more and eventually end up finding it harder and harder to remove the screw until it may become almost impossible.   Rubbery handled ones will help

Comment: LOL, that's apparently a stock photo of the screws.  The important aspect is the type of head the screwdriver fits into.  That picture managed to hide every single screw head.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Compaq Presario CQ50 Notebook PC Maintenance and Service Guide](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01572022.pdf) you will need a Phillips No.0 or No.1 screwdriver.

The guide has instructions, starting on page 47, for replacing the memory modules - after the preparatory steps you will need to

> Loosen the two Phillips PM2.5×6.0 captive screws that secure the memory module compartment cover to the computer.

Those screws should take a Phillips #1 screwdriver. Having a set of reasonable-quality screwdrivers as suggested in [Anaksunaman's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1484652/272824) would have you covered for if the Compaq ones happen to use a #0 size.

(Never buy really cheap screwdrivers: they are not a bargain because you can end up with damaged screw heads more easily.)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, I don't have the screw to open it. I didn't find what I need either when I searched the web.

It may be overkill in this case, but I purchased an iFixIt screwdriver set [similar to this one](https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Tools/Mako-Driver-Kit--64-Precision-Bits/IF145-299?o=4) a while back and it has worked on everything I have ever needed to repair, including laptops.

> On a side note: An odd and stupid question came to me — are all laptop screws the same?

In my experience, no.